# Operator "NOT LIKE" not work correctly

Tags: symfony, doctrine, dql

i am creating a new query in my app.
I use filters, with different options (Contain, equal or different).
If I use operator "different", my query generate like this:

```
SELECT p FROM ProductosBundle:Producto p 
LEFT JOIN p.tipo t 
LEFT JOIN p.departamento d 
WHERE 1=1 AND t.nombre NOT LIKE '%articulo%'
```

I have product different from "articulo", but return 0 results...

I tried with `NOT LIKE`, `!=` and `<>`, but not return results.

Is there something wrong in my condition where? I do not see the problem, with contain and equal it works.

Any idea? Thanks

EDIT 1:

This is my controller:

```
...
    $em = $this->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
            $dql = "SELECT p FROM ProductosBundle:Producto p LEFT JOIN p.tipo t LEFT JOIN p.departamento d";
            if (isset($_GET['filterField']) && isset($_GET['filterValue'])){
                $valores = explode(",",$_GET['filterValue']);
                $filas = explode(",",$_GET['filterField']);
                $operadores = explode(",",$_GET['filterOperator']);
                $dql .= " WHERE 1=1";
                for($i = 0; $i < count($valores); $i++){
                    $dql.= " AND ". $filas[$i]. " " . $operadores[$i] ;
                    if($operadores[$i] == "LIKE" OR $operadores[$i] == "NOT LIKE"){
                        $dql .= " '%".$valores[$i]."%'";
                    }else{
                        $dql .= " '".$valores[$i]."'";
                    }
                }
            }

        $query = $em->createQuery($dql);

        $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator');
        $productos = $paginator->paginate(
            $query,
            $request->query->get('page', 1),
            25
        );
```

EDIT2:

My profiler is executing this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p0_.id AS id_0 
FROM producto p0_ 
LEFT JOIN tipo t1_ ON p0_.tipo = t1_.id 
LEFT JOIN departamento d2_ ON p0_.departamento = d2_.id 
WHERE t1_.nombre LIKE 'articulo' 
AND 1 = 1 
AND t1_.nombre NOT LIKE '%articulo%' 
LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

Its a LIKE 'Articulo'... WHY???!!!

Comment: Your query doesn't contain any JOIN conditions - this looks suspicious.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt it's DQL, Doctrine adds conditions behind the scenes.

Comment: Can you include sample data?

Comment: Ivan, check the actual SQL query being run in Symfony Profiler and verify if it's what you expect it to be.

Comment: try to use not before column name NOT column like "val".
[refer to this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246365/check-if-string-doesnt-contain-another-string)

Comment: oh oh... @JakubMatczak, my profiler is executing this (In my 2nd edit)

Comment: use `||` instead of `OR` in `($operadores[$i] == "LIKE" OR $operadores[$i] == "NOT LIKE")`

Comment: Could you edit your question and add the values of: `$valores`, `$filas` and `$operadores` at the time of execution?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, there's an error in your UI logic / the code setting the query parameters. This:

```
   $valores = explode(",",$_GET['filterValue']);
   $filas = explode(",",$_GET['filterField']);
   $operadores = explode(",",$_GET['filterOperator']);
```

generates both

```
t1_.nombre LIKE 'articulo'
```

and

```
t1_.nombre NOT LIKE '%articulo%'
```

so you should take a look at the code that populates filterValue, filterField and filterOperator.

Comment: Yes, something error in my logic should be... But, this code generate a correct dql (First dql in my example)... I think that problem is inside of service knp_paginator